# Hexadecimal number too large for long long int?

Tags: c, hex, int, overflow, long-integer

Hope you can help me out here :)

I've ordered a RFID-tag and scanner for hobby use. The tag is sending input to tag, that I want to use in a C-program.

The problem is.. the tag is sending a code in hexadecimal - 10 characters - long.

I've tried to store this number in a long long int variable, but it doesn't seem to work.

When i print variable using printf, only the first 8 characters are printed. The rest (2 digits are left out).

```
long long int n1;
n1 = recieve_data();
printf("%lx", n1);
```

also i've tried to input 10 digit hexadecimal number myself, doing:

```
long long int n1;
scanf("%lx", &n1);
printf("%lx", n1);
```

I enter 10 digits 0 to F, but only 8 digits / characters are printed.

There must be some kind of integer overflow, but as far as I know:

1 digit in hex = 4 bit. Then 10 digits in hex = 40 bits ? - long long int should be sufficient !

If my instincts are right, and there is happening integer overflow, then how can I fix this ? Apparently no variable is large enough to hold the 10 digit hex value ?

Best regards
Nicolas - Denmark

Comment: %lx won't print any leading zeros.  If the first two digits of the hex string are not actually zero then you are not converting the hex string properly.  We can't see that code.

Comment: My bet is `sizeof long == 4`, so it should be `%llx`.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that your long long int is 64 bit wide, what i your environment, embedded, PC, 32 or 64 bit ? Compiler?

If your compiler is C99 compliant like gcc you can also use `stdint.h` and `uint64_t` which is guaranteed independent of platform to be 64 bits wide.

Your should recheck your `printf()` documentation, For example in my 64 bit OpenSuse box with gcc a `long` as well as `long lont int` are 64 bit wide via `sizeof()`. To print them I use:

`printf(" %llx ",hexNumber)`

Comment: If your compiler is C99 compliant then `long long int` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits long anyway.

Comment: With all the compilers and embedded platforms out there, nothing is guaranteed, there is even people doing C with Visual Studio c++.

Comment: Agreed, I was responding specifically to your paragraph that starts *"If your compiler is C99 compliant..."*

Answer (score 3):

10 hexadecimal characters is only 40 bits.  `long long int` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits, so it is fine for your use.

The problem is actually in your printf format string - `%lx` is the right format string for an `unsigned long int`, not a `long long int`.  To print a `long long int` you should use `%lld` - if you want to print it in hexadecimal, you should declare it as `unsigned long long int` instead, and use `%llx`.

Answer (score 2):

You are scanning and printing using %lx.

As I understand format strings %lx is a long int, not a long long int.  Depending on your hardware, you may only get 32 bits for a long int.

One of the other guys suggested %llx, for long long int.  It can't hurt to try that.

Answer (score 0):

Bring the number in in management sized parts and store it as a string.  Infinite length that way.

Comment: Thanks guys, it turned out to be i needed to store number as %l64 on Microsoft system.

Comment: Bring the number in in management sized parts and store it as a string. Infinite length that way. How would you do that ?

Answer (score 0):

> the tag is sending a code in hexadecimal - 10 characters

I'm pretty sure you mean "the tag is sending the RFID as a 10 character ASCII string, confined to the 16 hexadecimal digits"

> I've tried to store this number in a long long int variable,

*why*?

An `int`, and its friends, are *arithmetic* types. You use them to store values you plan to perform arithmetic on. You increment them, add 73 to them, bitshift them 3 to the left, bitwise OR them, or use them as an index.

But an RFID is just a *name*.  You don't do any of these things to a name, because it isn't meaningful to do so.  You wouldn't say "kermit the frog"+8, or "miss piggy"<<7 or "fozzie bear"%3. So it is with RFIDs.   You just read RFIDs in, compare them, maybe hash on them, and write them out. They are indivisible, inscrutable, "magic-cookie" strings - they're just tokens.

So you should store it as a string.  Not only does reading it into an int and then writing it back out to a string from an int generate two unnecessary convertions, it's semantically meaningless.